# How to transform the output of .values() function in django?

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I read in django docs that `.values()` returns a dictionary of desired fields and its values, like:

```
user_d = user_data.values('id','name', 'reporting_time')
```

It then returns me:

```
user_d = [{'id':'1','name':'Robert', 'reporting_time':'Evening'}, ...]
```

but I want:

```
user_d = {'1':['Robert', 'Evening'],...}
```

Please tell me how can I transform data to my desired format?
what I have tried is:

```
user_d_dict = dict((x, [y,z]) for x, y, z in user_d)
```

Comment: `.values()` on a models.Model or [Queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values) you mean? Please link to the Django docs section in your question with this statement.

Comment: you cant do it with `.values` . You will have to retrieve the queryset and manually process it to achieve what you are looking for

Comment: I don't really understand your desired format - you want a list of dicts, of which each dict has only one key/value pair? Why not a single dict of ids to lists?

Comment: @gertvdijk: yes at Queryset

Comment: @DanielRoseman: you are right it was my mistake to show the output uncleared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`values_list` gets you a list of lists, which is part of the way there. You'll still need to process it to create the dictionary. Something like:

```
user_dict = dict((d[0], [d[1], d[2]]) for d in 
                 user_data.values_list('id', 'name', 'reporting_time'))
```

Comment: ...or a dictionary comprehension: `user_dict = {d[0]: [d[1], d[2]] for d in user_data.values_list('id', 'name', 'reporting_time')}`